# Mouseenter runs even though cursor didn't move/leave/enter the parent

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouse, mouselistener, mouseenter

So, when you click on the element, `mouseenter` runs, even though it never left the parent, and `mouseleave` does not fire.

I have checked the MDN docs, and neither of the events bubble and aren't cancellable; so why does one run when the other doesn't?

The problem goes away if you use `style.display = 'none';` although then the elements aren't removed, and it doesn't work if you run both `display: none` and `remove()` at once.

Well I thought it ran because it thinks it leaves the parent for a split second but going by that logic `mouseleave` should've run too?

`e.stopPropagation()` has no effect, either

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset');

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  console.log('enter');
});

container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  console.log('leave');
});

reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.innerHTML = '';

  let i = 8;

  while (i--) {
    const block = document.createElement('div');
    block.addEventListener('click', () => {
      block.remove();
    });
    block.classList.add('block');
    container.append(block);
  }
});

for (const block of document.querySelectorAll('.block')) {
  block.addEventListener('click', () => {
    block.remove();
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  background: grey;
}

.container>.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.reset {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  background: grey;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<div class="reset">
  Reset
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/burzjpse/1/

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow seeking help with code must include the shortest - "*[mcve]*" - code necessary to reproduce the problem you describe, and with which you need help. Thank you for posting the live demo, that is always a bonus, but it doesn't replace the need for the code to be in the question itself. This time I've chosen to help, and do it for you, but next time please do this yourself.